# Vlookup with a drop down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, vlookup

I have an excel spreadsheet that has a drop down menu with two options. When one option is selected, I would like a cell in a different column to use the infromation selecetd in the drop down menu to vlookup a value. Whichever option is chose from the drop down menu pertains to different data. For example, in my drop down menu, the options are: "In-Town" and "Out of Town". It relates to whether or not employees are working in town or out of town. When "In town"  is selected, there is specific rates (hourly wages) that apply to that selection, and vice versa. How do I make the cell vlookup the selected value from the drop down menu?

Answer (score 0):

This works exactly as you have described it.  Set up the drop down using data validation, refer to the dropdown cell as the first  parameter in the vlookup (don't forget to lock it with the $ prefix).